# Missing keyword error due to nested case when

Tags: sql, nested, case

The following nested case when is causing a "missing keyword" error in my code (I use oracle sql)

```
   case when b2.vendname like '%ABC%'
        then case when b2.PO_NO = 123 then 'ABC'
                  when b2.PO_NO = 456 then 'XYZ'
                  when b2.tag_prefix = 'S' then 'PQR'
                  else 'MNO'
             end,
        else 'Not bought from ABC'
    end as "Orphan_Category"
```

If I remove this from my select and group by statements, the code runs without an error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: remove the colon after the first `end`

Answer (score 0):

case when b2.vendname like '%ABC%'
        then case when b2.PO_NO = 123 then 'ABC'
                  when b2.PO_NO = 456 then 'XYZ'
                  when b2.tag_prefix = 'S' then 'PQR'
                  else 'MNO'
             end
        else 'Not bought from ABC'
    end as "Orphan_Category"